# How do you properly check for an existing data in MongoDB Atlas database using PHP. I always get thet the name already exists

Tags: php, mongodb, authentication, nosql, mongodb-atlas

```
    $query = ['name' => $name];

    $options = [];
    $queryDriver = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($query, $options);

    $execute = $conn->executeQuery('db.collection', $queryDriver);

    //validation if a user exists
    if (!empty($execute)) {
      $err['name'] = 'this name already exists';
    } else {
      echo 'this name doesnt exist';
```

I am trying to create a register form but i can't validate if a name already exists.

Comment: Hi, please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. Good luck 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not connected to the database query result. In your code, you have in the first line

```
    $query = ['name' => $name];
```

and at the end of the script, you are checking

```
 if (!empty($query)) {
```

$query is not empty at this moment (it is `['name' => $name]`).
Instead of validating the query result, you are validating the query condition.

Comment: Have tried to put the executed query so `if (!empty($execute)) {` and it still doesnt work since that command executes the query

Comment: As you can see in the manual (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executequery.php) method executeQuery returns MongoDB\Driver\Cursor, it is not empty too. You can do this: ```$users = $conn->executeQuery('db.collection', $queryDriver)->toArray();
if (count($users) > 0) {...``` to check if user with name `$name` exists

Comment: thenk you very much now it works. I didnt know that you coud convert it to array. Have been checking this manual and as it seems i haven't gotten to know how to use the manual correctly. Thank you